# compile glibc without indirect functions

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, glibc

I am using PIN to instrument malloc/free from within glibc. PIN cannot instrument indirect functions and as in glibc ver 2.15+ malloc is defined as an ifunct. I believe reverting to an older ver of glibc (Ubuntu 12.04 uses 2.15) is close to impossible, so:

- To start with, what are indirect functions?
- Can I compile using gcc such that no ifunc's are created in shared libs?

thanks!

Comment: What is PIN? With _indirect functions_, do you refer to STT_GNU_IFUNC functions?

Comment: PIN =  dynamic binary instrumentation framework www.pintool.org